# Jenkins parameterized build - Parameters that are functions of other parameters

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to define these default values for parameters in my Jenkins parameterized build:

```
p1 = x
p2 = ${p1}y // should evaluate to "xy"
```

The problem is that when I build, `p2` gets set to `${p1}y` instead of `xy`.

[image: Jenkins job configuration (http://<domain>/jenkins/job/<job-name>/configure)]

Comment: Where are you setting these values?

Comment: I am setting these values in Jenkins job configuration (http://<domain>/jenkins/job/<job-name>/configure). I have added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a string parameter, You can add Pre-Built steps, in that do Execute Shell. Enter the below.

```
echo p2=${p1}y
```

So p2 will be accessible in the project. When you want to use the same, use **${p2}**